# Calling defer.notify() in synchronous context does not execute the callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

Consider the following snippet (**[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/XQnAnoqBV7ayYUffTapQ?p=preview)**):

```js
  function asyncCall() {
    var result = $q.defer();
    result.notify("Notify: sync");
    setTimeout(function () {
      result.notify("Notify: async (timeout)");
    }, 1000);
    return result.promise;
  }

  asyncCall().then(null /* success */, null /* error */, 
    function (notify) {
       console.log("Caller Notify: " + notify);
    }
  );
```

The first notify - `Notify: sync` - does not trigger the notify callback, I expected to see in console:

```js
Notify: sync
Notify: async (timeout)
```

But I got:

```js
Notify: async (timeout)
```

Is there a way to "queue" the `notify` call in a synchronous context and execute the callback twice?

Comment: the problem is your callback is registered after the `result.notify("Notify: sync");` has fired

Comment: You could do something like this...  But you cannot make it look synchronous i believe. http://plnkr.co/edit/jKsrHx?p=preview

Comment: Your first `.notify()` is triggered before the `.then()` method has run and attached your progress callback.  JS executes left to right through the chained methods.

Comment: @KhanhTO you should make it an answer so it's obvious what the issue was for future users with the issue.

Comment: Thank you all for the responses, the practical side of the problem can be either solved by:
(1) wrapping synchronous call to `defer.notify` in a `$timeout`, or 
(2) relying on a callback (not on `defer.notify`) to propagate progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @Benjamin Gruenbaum, I post my comment to the question as an answer:

There is no difference between calling synchronously and asynchrously.

The problem is your callback is registered after the `result.notify("Notify: sync");` **has fired.**